# Can't add rows to a Word table with vertically merged cells (VBA Excel Macro on Word Doc)

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

**I can't add rows to a word table! This is what the table looks like:
[Word Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ML7xh.png)**

**Code:**

```
wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.docx),*.docx", , "Please choose a file containing requirements to be imported")

If wdFileName = False Then Exit Sub '(user cancelled import file browser)


Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName) 'open Word file

With wdDoc

Set CurrentTable = wdDoc.Tables(1)
Set AddRow = CurrentTable.Rows.Add(AfterRow:=CurrentTable.Rows(9))

End With
```

**Error Message:  Cannot access individual rows in this collection because the table has vertically merged cells.**

**(VBA Excel Macro on Word Doc)**

Comment: On the inicial page you have the merge and centralize button, like this image: http://www.howtoexcelatexcel.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/Merge-and-Centre2.jpg . On Excel, if two or more cells are merged, you can't add rows or line between them

Comment: @danieltakeshi The word document has merged cells - not the excel spreadsheet. I'm performing all these functions on the word document, not the excel spreadsheet! However I'm using an excel macro to write all the code!

Comment: If you try to add a row manually, it is added if you select a row. So reading in some forums you will find that the Insert function needs to be used. Unfortunatelly, i don't have experience in word VBA, so i can't help you further.